# Common meanings of "reverse", "revert", "invert", and "inverse"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, difference, word-difference

Here's an interesting question. I sense that these two have common meanings. All of them have meanings connected with "opposite","upside down","back".

How different are they while being so indifferent in many ways?

Comment: I think the question was very clear. For an ELL, the specificity of the meaning can be very confusing. I believe I clarified the specific ways the words can be used. To the untrained eye, they can seem the same but they all have specific uses. Also, there is the noun/adjective bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fyi, indifferent is not the antonym of different]: Alike and different

**What does one reverse? What's its semantic trait?** 1) **One reverses a course of action** or **the direction or path a physical object takes** (if the course of action is to do A), B), C) and D), reversing it would be to do: D), C), B) and A).

For example: He drove to New York via Route 1, then reversed his route on the way home. He drove his car down the driveway, then reversed it back up into the garage. This is from the LATIN revertere: to change direction: revertere: turn back, go back, return; recur; It is **a verb and an adjective**: the reverse direction or to take the reverse path home.

**What does revert mean? What's its semantic trait?** 2) **One reverts to an earlier state or condition**. It is a **verb** only.  Here, the object or person does not move down a path or line; the entire object or person becomes what it was before.

For example: The man recently experience great happiness [a state] but then reverted to his old ways [not feeling happiness]. Or:  John removed the updates so the program reverted to an earlier version. Also from LATIN: revertere: to turn back.

**What does invert mean? What's its semantic trait?** 3) **One inverts two things by having them change position or their positions are changed to the opposite one**.

For example: The levers on the machine were supposed to be marked Lever A and Lever B, but John inverted them. [He switched their positions]. OR: temperature inversion (please google that. Layers of warm and cold air change position) OR: Her name is Mary Smith-Collins but you inverted it to: Mary Collins-Smith. 
invertere turn upside down; pervert; change; **Invert is  only a verb**.

**What does inverse mean? What's its semantic trait?** **Inverse is the adjective or noun for the verb invert**: His name is John Smith. Inverted, his name is Smith John. The inverse of his name is Smith John. They don't like inverted commas (British for quotation marks. Can you see why? :) Also, from invetere in Latin.

Inverse (noun) also has a special meaning in logic:

You can see the logical notation for it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_(logic).
Here is the example they give, without the notation:
For example, substituting propositions in natural language for logical variables, the inverse of the conditional proposition, "If it's raining, then Sam will meet Jack at the movies" is "If it's not raining, then Sam will not meet Jack at the movies."

I hope I've hit the major points here....

Comment: Play the song in reverse. Invert the song and play it. Play the song inverse.

Comment: Sorry, you can only play a song in reverse if you music player will do it. That goes along with my definition. You cannot invert a song, really. You can invert two songs in a playlist. And "play the song inverse" is not  idiomatic.